# iOS browser throws Phishing warning

Tags: ios, safari, phishing

We have a site, `mysite.com`, which links to another site of ours, `mydemo.com`.

The link is `https://demouser:password@subdomain.mydemo.com`, and in iOS, when users click on the link, because of the username and password. Below is the image :

[image: they get a phishing warning]

Is there some possibility to tell the iOS browser that this is not a phishing attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a direct link, use a PHP file with a redirect like this one

```
<?php function redirect($url, $statusCode = 302)
  {
     header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
     die();
  }
$url = 'https://demouser:password@subdomain.mydemo.com';
redirect($url); ?>
```

If you need a dynamic link (different users, different link) use a PHP file like this with a form leading to it.

demo.php:

```
<?php function redirect($url, $statusCode = 302)
  {
     header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
     die();
  }
$url = 'https://' . $_POST['user'] . ':' . $_POST['password'] . '@subdomain.mydemo.com';
redirect($url); ?>
```

and 
login.htm

```
<form action='demo.php' method='post'>
  Username <input type='text' name='user'><br>
  Password <input type='password' name='password'><br>
 <input type='submit' value='login'>
</form>
```